# How to make get_users' arguments "or" and not "and"

Tags: wordpress

I know you can do 'relation' => 'OR' in Meta_Query, but how do you do that in get_users's themselves?
For example something like

```
get_users( array( 
  
'role__in' => array( 'author', 'subscriber' ) ) 

or
  
'search' => 'john'  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked a query we have updated the query use can use this code.

```
get_users( array( 
  
'role__in' => array( 'author', 'subscriber' ) ) 

'relation' => 'OR',
  
'search' => 'john'  );
```